# Nginx basic authentication, login from command line

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

As I know browser login user nginx basic authentication server with -H 'Authorization: Basic username:password' header.

But in case of my application, the client uses command lines calling REST API, which I can't modify. So there is no way for me to inject user credential in the header. The question is how nginx server to be configured to remember user, and allow user to log out without credential sent in every request?

For example, user types commands from terminal:

```
login myhost.com -u myname:mypassword
```

then this user is authorized to access the sever, he/she can retrieve information by provided APIs.

```
logout myhost.com
```

then this user logs out.

Comment: It's unclear what you asking. For basic auth, header must be in every request. How would you know if it's the same user unless client send some identity. It's `Authorisation` header in case of basic auth, or some cookie in usual web apps

Comment: I am reading about http basic authentication. It seems including user:pass in the header is necessary. Actually I am looking for something that remembers users in session.

Comment: But session implementations in 99.99% cases makes use of cookies. The only thing you have besides headers is connection ip and hostname. Anyway, what the problem for user to add auth header to requests?

Comment: Ok, it seems I should find another way.

Comment: This looks like a use for cookies. Although your client must support them.